# Jquery - How do I use each appendTo or prependTo (Close)

Tags: jquery, append, each, prepend

Html code

```
<div class="ar">
    <div class="IntroText">
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        <span class="youtube">
        <object =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
        </object>
        </span>
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxx
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ar">
    <div class="IntroText">
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxx
        </div>
</div>
<div class="ar">
    <div class="IntroText">
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        <span class="youtube">
        <object =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
        </object>
        </span>
        <span class="youtube">
        <object =xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
        </object>
        </span>
        xxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxx
        </div>
</div>
```

How do I use jQuery each function 
prepend the first span.youtube element to class ar? or appendTo?
I try use jquery each but all span.youtube element will go the same

```
$(.IntroText).find(span.youtube).each(function(){$(this).appendTo('.IntroText')}
```

Comment: Yes,i'm,but still forgot how to use each functon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move first `span.youtube` element then you have to iterate through `.IntroText` elements and find first `span.youtube` like this;

```
$('.IntroText').each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.before($this.find('span.youtube:first'));
});
```

This moves first `span.youtube` element before each `.IntroText` element. You can use `.after()` too if it's what you need.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Wcv/) is a jsFiddle example that you can see the markup after modification.

Comment: thnaks,Emre but i have new problem,my youtube element can't see maybe  jquery length problem?

Comment: my fault,i forgot i change the element class name,thanks again,have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('.IntroText').find('span.youtube').each(function(){$('<p>prepend sometext</p>').prependTo(this)});
$('.IntroText').find('span.youtube').each(function(){$('<p>append sometext</p>').appendTo(this)});    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SXBwh/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is very clunky but it looks like it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ZSdXS/

```
$('.IntroText span.youtube').each(function(){
   $('.IntroText').append(this);
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?

You need to wrap html elements, id's and classes in single or double quotes inside the function.